# is it better to use a parameterized route or call a component each time

Tags: angular

is it better to use a parameterized route or to call a component each time
e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <app-user [user]="user"></app-user> <== app-user is a selector
</div>
```

or would it be better to use a parameterized route: e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users" routerlink=”/user/{{user.id}”>
    {{ user.FirstName }} {{ user.LastName }} plus some other code...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the purpose you want to achieve.

If you want your user (i.e. the user that is currently brwosing your application, not the `user` variable) to be able to mark your page as a favorite, you should use the routing. This way, when he opens the page, the UserComponent is directly loaded, and the user is fetched.

If you make an overlay giving informations about a user when your hover over a profile picture, then you should use the selector.

This is really up to you, there's no rule for that.

If you still have trouble chosing, please, let us know what your purpose is, so that we can drive you to the right use for your component.